# Explanation for `Sup objRef;`

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

Can anyone explain me about this statement mean `Sup objRef;`.  this block code is not error and I understand how to instantiate class. but I don't why in this example they(the book owner) have write this `Sup objRef;` after instantiate class.

```
package basic.code;

class Sup{
    void who(){
        System.out.println("Who in Sup");
    }
}

class Sup1 extends Sup{
    void who(){
        System.out.println("Who in Sup1");
    }
}

class Sup2 extends Sup{
    void who(){
        System.out.println("Who in Sup2");
    }
}

public class DynamicMethodDispatch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Sup obj = new Sup();
        Sup1 obj1 = new Sup1();
        Sup2 obj2 = new Sup2();

        Sup objRef;

        objRef = obj;
        objRef.who();

        objRef = obj1;
        objRef.who();

        obj2.who();
    }
}
```

Comment: Really?  You're writing code full of polymorphism, and you don't know what a variable declaration is?

Comment: As David has stated, it's only a polymorphic example. objRef is a Sup object and can be used to reference two different classes Sup1 and Sup2 because both extend Sup.

Comment: @DavidWallace i'm just a starter.

Comment: Well, it looks like you have skipped straight to chapter 9 of your book, without reading chapter 1.

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
Sup objRef;

objRef = obj;
objRef.who();

objRef = obj1;
objRef.who();
```

is demonstrating the effect of polymorphism.

`Sup objRef` creates a new variable of type `Sup`. It does not set it to any value. On the next line, `objRef` is set to equal to `obj`. The line after that prints "Who in Sup". Then "magic" happens. `objRef` is set to `obj1`, which is of type `Sup1`. The next line calls `who()` and "Who in Sup1" is printed. Why? Because although `obj` is of type `Sup`, the object stored in it is `Sup1`.

> Why does the book show `Sup objRef` then? Why does it not do `Sup objRef = obj;`

I don't think this has any practical purposes. It is just so that the next two blocks of code looks neat.